# SQL duplicate records with unique scenario

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[image: Sample Data]

I am working on solving the duplicates on the above data where I need to exclude the data with the same **Amount** where **Category = 'Own'**

As you can noticed on the sample data that I created, all dates from **Category = Seller** are always at the first day of the month and on **Own** category is always different, which giving me headache to think of the logic on how to solve it.

Own and Seller category are joined together on the CTE table that is why the dates are not that consistent on **Own**

The output that I'm expecting is to get all the data on both Category but if the duplicate Amount exist on **Own**, it should not be included because this is duplicate. Date on **Own** category should always be converted to first day of the month in order to compare the amount and date together.

I tried using the codes below but I'm missing something here because it only gets which records = 1 either the **Category** is **Own** or **Seller**

```
WITH TestTable AS (
    SELECT --DATA FROM EXTERNAL TABLE
    Product,
    Account,
    Category = 'Own',
    Amount,
    Date
    FROM exttbl

    UNION

    SELECT
    Product,
    Account,
    Category = 'Seller',
    Amount,
    Date
    FROM inttbl
)

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
    RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Product, Account, Amount, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, date), 0) ORDER BY Date),
    Product,
    Account,
    Category,
    Amount,
    Date
    FROM TestTable
) a
WHERE a.RowNum = 1
```

Is there any kind of approach on how to solve this?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: I added MySQL intentionally to get atleast some kind of logic from experts on how to solve it. Ideas.

Comment: Appreciate it, thank you. Updated the tags now.

Comment: *all dates from Category = Seller are always at the first day of the month* Does your table structure contains according CHECK constraint? if not then you are too presumptuous.

Comment: Those with category = own are come from external table. meaning it is from 2 different sources and I used a CTE table to join the data together by using union. What showing here is the Final SELECT and I need to come up with a solution to remove the duplicate scenario I mentioned

Comment: What if two Own rows exist on same month with same amount? Perhaps you should fix your union

Comment: Updated the description for more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to row-number by month, then conditionally filter it

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Product, Account, Amount, EOMONTH(Date) ORDER BY Date),
      Product,
      Account,
      Category,
      Amount,
      Date
    FROM YourTable t
) t
WHERE (Category = 'Seller' OR rn = 1);
```

Comment: Ohhhhh man! This is what I am missing! That where clause filter works like magic! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

So from your question I do understand that you only want to skip own if its amount is already exists in seller row. I came up with this logic you can optimize it use proper variables to reuse the table I am just giving you the idea that this can be done like that.  you can add this in your current query however you like.

```
 select * from TestTable where Category <> 'Own'
    union 
    select * from TestTable where Category = 'Own' and Amount not in (
       select Amount from TestTable where Category <> 'Own'
    )
```

Comment: Appreciate it, im trying the logic here

Comment: I tried this but it is excluding all those with same Amount regardless of their dates. Do I need a subquery again on the where clause to compare the dates? Dates on Own category should be converted always to first day of the month to compare it on the Seller category.

Comment: can you explain me what you actually want with the date so i can provide the query accordingly thanks.

Comment: In order to compare the amount on Own category, date should be considered as well. Like on the screenshot I have provided. Example is for the month of february. Same amount but different dates. My idea is to convert the date then next is compare the amount. Am i right? I have updated the description on my post as well.

Comment: I have a Question can there be multiple seller records in one month with same product ? basically is there any unique field init ?

Comment: Yes, there are multiple seller records in one month. Account = AccountID so that is unique id and I just provided same AccountID on my example screenshot to show the flow of records every month.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM TestTable t1
WHERE Category <> 'Own'
   OR NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM TestTable t2
                   WHERE DATETRUNC(month, t1.date) = t2.date
                     AND t2.Category = 'Seller'
                     AND t1.Product = t2.Product
                     AND t1.Account = t2.Account
                     AND t1.Amount = t2.Amount
                  )
```

Comment: Appreciate it, im trying the logic here

Comment: @LetSooGas The answer provided by Muhammad Hunain realizes the same logic, and if you'd use NOT EXISTS instead of WHERE NOT IN in his solution then such query should be the most fast one...

Comment: okay, im trying to apply it on my code. btw I have updated the description.